# terraform resource block loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am working on setting up VPC Service control in GCP using [google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/access_context_manager_service_perimeter) provider. In this resource, within [status](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/access_context_manager_service_perimeter#nested_status) block, I have to specify a list of google projects as `resources` value in the format `"projects/123456789"`. I want to put the project numbers in a variable and created something like this.

```
variable "project_numbers_to_protect" {
  type = list(any)
  default = [
    "123456",
    "456789",
    "894321"
  ]
}
```

I am able to reference the variable as below.

```
resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[0]}",
             "projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[1]}",
             "projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[2]}"]
```

But in my production case, I have a large number of projects in the list and I am looking for option to reference it dynamically. I tried `count` option, but that didn't work.

```
count = var.project_numbers_to_protect
resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[count.index]}"]
```

Error message

```
vpc-sc-module $ terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
│
│   on vpc-sc-copy.tf line 16, in resource "google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter" "regular_service_perimeter":
│   16:     resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[count.index]}"]
│
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
╵
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

***Full Code***

vpc-sc-copy.tf

```
resource "google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter" "regular_service_perimeter" {
  parent                    = "accessPolicies/${var.access_context_manager_policy_number}"
  name                      = "accessPolicies/${var.access_context_manager_policy_number}/servicePerimeters/${var.perimeter_name}"
  perimeter_type            = var.perimeter_type
  title                     = var.perimeter_name
  use_explicit_dry_run_spec = false
  status {
    restricted_services = var.restricted_services
    ## Below two lines works.
    # resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[0]}",
    #   "projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[1]}",]
    ## Below option doesn't work
    count = var.project_numbers_to_protect
    resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[count.index]}"]
    ingress_policies {
      ingress_from {
        identity_type = "ANY_IDENTITY"

        sources {
          access_level = "*"
        }
      }

      ingress_to {
        resources = [
            "*"
          ]
        dynamic "operations" {
          for_each = var.ingress_rule1_service_name
          content {
            service_name = operations.value
            method_selectors {
              method = "*"
            }
          }
        }


      }
    }
    egress_policies {
      egress_from {
        identities = ["serviceAccount:service-${var.project_number_to_protect}@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
      }
      egress_to {
        resources = [
          "projects/${var.egress_rule1_project_number}"
        ]
        operations {
          service_name = "storage.googleapis.com"
          dynamic "method_selectors" {
            for_each = var.egress_rule1_methods
            content {
              method = method_selectors.value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    egress_policies {
      egress_from {
        identity_type = "ANY_IDENTITY"
      }
      egress_to {
        resources = [
          "projects/${var.egress_rule2_project_number}"
        ]
        operations {

          service_name = "storage.googleapis.com"
          dynamic "method_selectors" {
            for_each = var.egress_rule2_methods
            content {
              method = method_selectors.value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


  }
}
```

***Relevant section of vars.tf***

```
variable "project_numbers_to_protect" {
  type = list(any)
  default = [
    "123456",
    "456789",
    "894321"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the full context where you are using your `count`? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin

`vpc-sc-module $ terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context
│
│   on vpc-sc-copy.tf line 16, in resource "google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter" "regular_service_perimeter":
│   16:     resources = ["projects/${var.project_numbers_to_protect[count.index]}"]
│
│ The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
╵
vpc-sc-module $`

Comment: Please update the question with correctly formated errors and code blocks. What is the full source code for your `google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter`?

Comment: @Marcin I just added the full resource block and variable definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error writes, you can't use `count` the way you want. Instead it should be:

```
resource "google_access_context_manager_service_perimeter" "regular_service_perimeter" {
  parent                    = "accessPolicies/${var.access_context_manager_policy_number}"
  name                      = "accessPolicies/${var.access_context_manager_policy_number}/servicePerimeters/${var.perimeter_name}"
  perimeter_type            = var.perimeter_type
  title                     = var.perimeter_name
  use_explicit_dry_run_spec = false
  status {
    restricted_services = var.restricted_services





    resources = [for project_number in var.project_numbers_to_protect:
                 "projects/${project_number}" ]





    ingress_policies {
      ingress_from {
        identity_type = "ANY_IDENTITY"

        sources {
          access_level = "*"
        }
      }

      ingress_to {
        resources = [
            "*"
          ]
        dynamic "operations" {
          for_each = var.ingress_rule1_service_name
          content {
            service_name = operations.value
            method_selectors {
              method = "*"
            }
          }
        }


      }
    }
    egress_policies {
      egress_from {
        identities = ["serviceAccount:service-${var.project_number_to_protect}@gcp-sa-aiplatform-cc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
      }
      egress_to {
        resources = [
          "projects/${var.egress_rule1_project_number}"
        ]
        operations {
          service_name = "storage.googleapis.com"
          dynamic "method_selectors" {
            for_each = var.egress_rule1_methods
            content {
              method = method_selectors.value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    egress_policies {
      egress_from {
        identity_type = "ANY_IDENTITY"
      }
      egress_to {
        resources = [
          "projects/${var.egress_rule2_project_number}"
        ]
        operations {

          service_name = "storage.googleapis.com"
          dynamic "method_selectors" {
            for_each = var.egress_rule2_methods
            content {
              method = method_selectors.value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.